# PROC IML trapezoidal rule

Tags: sas, calculus, sas-iml

```
proc iml;
start tr(x,y); * create function called tr;

N = nrow(x);
dx = x[2:N] - x[1:N-1];
ymean = (y[2:N] + y[1:N-1]) / 2;
return(dx` * ymean );
finish tr;

x = do(-2,5,0.01);
print "Integral of a over x is" ( tr(x,0#x+1) ); *Answer is 7;
```

I keep receiving the (execution) invalid subscript or subscript out of range. How do I solve this problem and get the correct answer? I've tried taking out the -1 in x[1:N-1]; and y[1:N-1], but it gives me the wrong answer. Is it because I need to assume equally spaced intervals? If so, how would I do that.
Trapezoidal equation: (x-x0)*(y+y0)/2 or  (xi - xi-1) * (yi + yi-1) / 2.

Answer (score 0):

The subscript problem arises from the fact that `x` is being treated as a row vector rather than a column vector, so `nrow(x) = 1`. That means you've defined `n = 1`, so when the index is `n-1`, it's actually at 0. That causes a subscript error since SAS IML vectors are indexed from 1 rather than 0. To fix it, use `n = ncol(x)`.

Also, as an aside, you can shorten your module `tr` if you wanted:

```
proc iml;
    start tr(x, y);
        i = 2:ncol(x);
        return( (x[i] - x[i-1])` * (y[i] + y[i-1]) / 2 );
    finish tr;

    x = do(-2, 5, 0.01);

    print 'The integral of a over x is' (tr(x, 0#x+1)) 'and should be 7.';
quit;
```