# Trapezoidal Rule in PROC IML

Tags: sas

Build an IML module tr that calculates an integral (“area under the curve”) using the trapezoidal rule. The module should accept vectors `x` and `y` as input parameters and return the value of `auc`. Show that your module works by applying it as follows:

```
x = do(-2,5,0.01);         
print "Integral of a over x is" ( tr(x,0#x+1) );         
print "Integral of b over x is" ( tr(x,1#x) );         
print "Integral of c over x is" ( tr(x,x##2) );        
print "Integral of d over x is" ( tr(x,abs(x)) );         
print "Integral of y over x is" ( tr(x,sin(x##2)) );         
print "Integral of z over x is" ( tr(x,log(2+exp(x))) );
```

Here is my code:

```
proc iml;
start tr(x, y);
    do i=1 to 2000;
    auc = (sum(x[i]-(x[i-1]))#(y[i]+(y[i-1])))/2;
    return (auc);
    end;
finish;
```

When I try to run the verification code provided, I get the error message that the subscript is invalid or out of date. What does this mean and how do I fix my code so that it works?

Comment: Why are you trying to index a vector `x` of length 701 with values between (and including) 0 and 2000?

Comment: I am still fiddling with that one, but this definitely works.

    proc iml;
    start tr(x,y); 
     n = ncol(x);
     dx = x[2:n] - x[1:n-1];
     ymean = (y[2:n] + y[1:n-1]) / 2;
     return(dx` * ymean );
    finish tr;

Answer (score 0):

The x only has one row, transpose your x by adding `.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here. First off, you don't need to do looping in side your module if the arguments are being passed as vectors. Second, you're indexing `i` from 1 but you use `i-1`, which evaluates to 0 when `i`=1. This causes a subscript error since IML vectors are indexed from 1, not 0 like in C. You'll also get a subscript error whenever `x` and `y` have length greater than 2000 since you're referencing elements of the vectors which don't exist.

This is a succinct way of getting what you need:

```
proc iml;
    start tr(x, y);
        i = 2:ncol(x);
        return( (x[i] - x[i-1])` * (y[i] + y[i-1]) / 2 );
    finish;

    <verification code goes here>
quit;
```

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557047/proc-iml-trapezoidal-rule/27448177#27448177), but there are no upvoted or accepted answers to that question as of this posting so I'm unable to mark this as a duplicate. It was even posted on the same day.

Also, this smells like homework. If it is homework, please mention so in your post.